# Path.equals method clarification

Tags: java, path, equals, nio

Directly from this [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
     equals

     boolean equals(Object other)

     Tests this path for equality with the given object.

     If the given object is not a Path, or is a Path associated with a different FileSystem, then this method returns false.

     Whether or not two path are equal depends on the file system implementation. In some cases the paths are compared without regard to
 case, and others are case sensitive. This method does not access the
 file system and the file is not required to exist. Where required, the
 isSameFile method may be used to check if two paths locate the same
 file.

     This method satisfies the general contract of the Object.equals method.

     Overrides:
         equals in class Object
     Parameters:
         other - the object to which this object is to be compared
     Returns:
         true if, and only if, the given object is a Path that is identical to this Path
```

First they say:

**1)**

> If the given object is not a Path, or is a Path associated with a
>   different FileSystem, then this method returns false.

Then they say:

**2)**

> This method does not access the file system and the file is not required to exist.

If point number **2** is true, how does the jvm check point **1** ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Path represents the system dependent file path, but not the actual file. It does not need to access the file system.

Comment: what if is a different file system with the same pattern of describing a path?